# What is difference between these identical web sites?

Tags: html, css

I could not find what is the reason of http://yeni.abantsu.com.tr/ doesnt work on mobile (html doesnt look way I expect) while identical this website works on mobile ok. http://www.asisaotokiralama.com/abant/

I could not find te difference between these two web sites.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Well they have different urls for a start.....

Comment: turns out they actually look different too, who'd of guessed. My guess is the HTML may be different, possibly some of the images and maybe the CSS, have I missed anything?

Comment: On both sites the elements are positioned absolutely, so neither will display properly on mobile.

Comment: Add this '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">' It will work.

Comment: it already has <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

Comment: @berotomanya - Edited. Change to  `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Answer (score 2):

There are many tools that can run "diffs" between two files -- highlighting the lines where the code differs between them. One is the `Compare` plugin for `Notepad++`

It only takes a moment, and I can see *lots* of differences between the source code of these two (not) identical sites.

- yeni.abantsu.com.tr has reference to stylesheets for fancybox, asisaotokiralama.com does not.
- The nav-links in the asisaotokiralama.com are all broken (just hashes `#`)
- The footers have different HTML structures

...etc.

Answer (score 0):

not expected result is because, lack of below meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```